# Issue with JPA 2.0 EnityManger.createNativeQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am running the following statement

```
List<TableA> tableAList = (List<TableA>) entityManager.
                          createNativeQuery(
                          "select colA, colB from tableA", 
                          TableA.class)
                          .getResultList();
```

TableA entity

```
@Enitity
@Column(name = "tableA")
public class TableA {
   @Id
   private Integer id;

   @Column(name = "colA")
   private Integer colA;

   @Column(name = "colB")
   private Integer colB;

   @Column(name = "colC")
   private Integer colC;

   @Column(name = "colD")
   private Integer colD;

   /*
     Corresponding getters and setters. Excluding them for brevity.
   */
}
```

The above query throws SQLException that "colC" is not found. If I add colC in the select list, it says "colD" not found. Essentially, it is expecting all the columns of the table to be included in the select query. The same error doesn't happen if I don't add the resultClass and just get the response as `List<Object[]>`. Can anyone explain why this behaviour occurs?

Is there a way to get the response as List setting the rest of the fields to null (or default primitives if there are any primitive fields)?

Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'colC' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2759)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:985)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:991)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
```

Note: I am using JPA 2.0.

Comment: Why don't you just define an entity with the fields that you are actually selecting from your database?
If you tell JPA the result is of a certain class, it will make sure that all attributes are extracted from the result set. The values from the resultset may be null, but the column within the resultset must exist.

Comment: I would have created an entity if the select combination is static. I am using a query builder and we can select any combination of the columns. Is there any other way for me to make the select columns dynamic?

Comment: If you select a dynamic amount of columns, then mapping this to an entity is a strange thing then; of course you could rewrite your SQL query to select the other columns as null values. That is, each column that you do not want to retrieve from the table, you include as "null AS <column-name>" in your query. That is in your case above "select a.colA as colA, a.colB as colB, null as colC, null as colD from tableA a"

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify the `resultClass` the JPA cannot know what type of result to give you, so it returns an array of all the column values. Each `Object[]` is one returned row.

If you want to not fetch colC and colD, but still use a result class, you have to put in fake fields of their corresponding names and data types.

```
List<TableA> tableAList = (List<TableA>) entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                  "select colA, colB, null as colC, null as colD from tableA", 
                  TableA.class).getResultList();
```

If your fields happen to be primitive, use 0 instead of null.

Comment: Is there a config or something of ResultHandler kind which does this for me? Because I don't want to include the dummy null and default primitive values in each of my queries.

Comment: No. You can, however create a different, smaller Entity class to use just for that.

Comment: I cannot do that. My entity classes typically contain upto 15 fields and I can select any combination of them.

Comment: Then perhaps it would be easier to filter the output to the user, rather than the fetch from the database. Considering you say they're up to 15 fields, unless many of them are large binary or text blobs, it shouldn't be a performance drain. I have a table with 72 columns and it's growth rate is finally slowing down.

Comment: I agree we can do that. I am curious that if I make multiple database calls and do a select * each time like you suggested, even then there wouldn't be a performance drain? Selecting multiple columns won't alter the database performance. Network overhead is what matters. Doing a select * might be just a few bytes over the network. But still if we have multiple db calls, will that not degrade the performance? I am expecting something of the sort which fills in default values if not selected. Something like say ResultSetHandler.

Comment: I believe for MySQL specifically the queries are not cached server-side for multiple invocations. In PostgreSQL they are, but if you close the EntityManager (as you should on each request to avoid connection leaks), then all per-connection resources, like cached queries get released.